# Flexible design approach vs maintainabilty/verifiability

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Currently, I have to define a general design approach concerning the future extensibility of a software written in C#. The software is built in modular design: A main part doing the general handling, and several manager/driver classes who operate the hardware, handle the database etc. The goal is to create the software as flexible as possible with respect to future changes, while keeping maintenance and verification effort low.

As an example, consider hardware device Type1 which implements IDevice. Example:

```
interface IDevice
{
    double Measure(double range);
}

class Type1 : IDevice
{
    public double Measure(double range);
}
```

In the future, there will probably be device Type2 which will need additional functions not defined in IDevice, e.g.:

```
class Type2 : IDevice
{
    public double Measure(double range);
    public void SpecialSetup(byte flags);
}
```

Since my driver only knows IDevice objects, calling `IDevice.SpecialSetup()` is not possible. Which is the best way to go forward in order to change as few modules as possible?

1.) One solution I was suggested was to read out all functions for devices from an XML file. The method name, device type and input parameters would be parsed, and the method with parameters would then be called using reflection. Since the program consists of a defined measure run, all methods will be called one after the other until the XML file is read completely. The text file would look something like that:

```
<Method Name="Measure" Device="Type1"> 
    <Range=0.01 /> 
</Method>
<Method ...
```

This approach provides maximum flexibility: In the future I can simply add a new Type2.dll, add a method "SpecialSetup" to the XML file, and then readout the XML file. The measure run will then include the call to device Type2. No need to change anything in the program; changing the XML and adding the Type2.dll will be sufficient.

However, I have a bad feeling about this. There is no type safety, the compiler will not be able to find any errors in the XML file and thus all errors will only show at runtime, and in general, using reflection like this seems like a bad code smell. Moreover, verification is more difficult, so it seems I am trading flexibility for maintainability and verifiability.

2.) I could create a new interface IType3 with the additional function:

```
interface IType3
{
    void SpecialSetup(byte flags);
}
```

The corresponding driver function would be something like

```
public DoSetup(IDevice device, byte flags)
{
    IType3 dev = device as IType3;
    if (dev != null)
        dev.SpecialSetup(flags);
    else
        throw new InvalidCastException();
}
```

While this preserves more maintainability and makes verification easier, it loses a bit of flexibility: For each change, I have to adapt the interfaces as well as the driver, so I have to touch more than just the device DLL. Still, it feels like cleaner code.

Am I right that option 1 is ugly coding? Or is it fine to do it that way? Maybe there is a better solution than 1 AND 2?

Comment: The ability to define program behaviour within configuration data doesn't add flexibility nor extensibility. It only bypasses quality controls such as testing, versioning, source control and change management.   Of course, you could view the removal of quality controls as a form of flexibility because it certainly saves a lot of time when you can dive straight into a production service to "monkey patch" changes on-the-fly,  but if that's what you really need then you may as well just keep the compiled language and allow direct deployment into production straight from a developer's IDE.

Comment: @BenCottrell indeed. Sadly, I've known people to deploy code off developer machines and won't even acknowledge it's highly problematic. Makes me want to pull my hair out

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of how you define your types, the problem remains that your main program has to know to call things. For example, if you have a driver that has a  `SpecialSetup` method, your main program has to know to call it and know how to compute its arguments. So even if you come up with some clever way to get your types to expose different members, you still have the problem of the main program knowing which members to call and what to pass to them.

The solution is to make the interface generic. It is the driver's responsibility to translate the interface call into a device-specific class call.

```
interface IDevice
{
    void Initialize(IDeviceConfiguration configuration);
    double Measure(double range);
}

class Type1 : IDevice
{
    public Initialize(IDeviceConfiguration config) 
    {
        //No operation
    }
    
    public double Measure(double range);
}

class Type2 : IDevice
{
    public double Measure(double range);
    public Initialize(IDeviceConfiguration config) 
    {
        byte deviceFlags = (config.HasFeature1 ? 1 : 0)
                         & (config.HasFeature2 ? 2 : 0)
                         & (config.HasFeature3 ? 4 : 0);
        this.SpecialSetup(deviceFlags);
    }

    private void SpecialSetup(byte flags)  //Notice this is private
    {
        //Do your special setup here
    }
}
```

Comment: I also thought about this, but this only works in the special case where I can put the method into a more general method from the interface. If SpecialSetup() has to be called somewhere after Initialization(), but not during a Measure(), e.g. to change parameters of the device between two measurements, your solution won't work. Unfortunately, this is my situation.

Comment: If the calling program needs to be able to change the parameters of the device between two measurements, you should probably expose a `ChangeParameters` method so it can call it. So add it to the interface. Not sure how you could avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

(1) is nothing but an attempt to turn your current language into one that supports [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). If you want to discover if the methods you need to call exist at run time rather than compile time then go use a language that supports duck typing. Retrofitting it into a language that worked hard to ensure it  didn't support duck typing is just confusing and messy.

(2) Why use the fancy new `as` cast that returns a null when the cast fails if you're just going to throw an exception when it's null? Ends up behaving the same as the old school cast. If you really need to be able to call `SpecialSetup()` then you really need `device` to be an `IType3`. If so then change

```cs
public DoSetup(IDevice device, byte flags)
```

to

```cs
public DoSetup(IType3 device, byte flags)
```

And now the compile time type safety actually works.

Comment: The disadvantage is that if I use ´´´DoSetup(IType3 device)´´´, the calling module must know IType3 as well, so in case of a change where IType3 is implemented, I have to change the calling module as well.

Comment: @Thern you have it backwards. The calling module is expressing what it needs. When the needs of the calling module change that is when a new IType would be needed. Who cares about IType4 if nothing uses it?

Comment: Maybe I do make a conceptual mistake (I hope so). But in my situation. Device2 needs an action (e.g. a recalibration or a specific setup) that Device1 doesn't need. This recalibration/setup can't be included in the initialization, so it must be called later on. But the calling module isn't really interested in these device specific issues, it just wants some values to be measured. So we have the case that the calling module has to cater to the device specific needs even though it isn't interested in them.

Comment: It's pointless to create new methods without something that calls them. If you refuse to create anything that knows them enough to call them then reflection is your only choice. But creating new methods isn't the only way to solve this problem. If you want the driving code to be generic stop creating things for it to care about.